# Evince loses all open files during restarts?

Tags: evince

Had many open pdfs in evince. Had to restart for some update. On reopen, evince showed recent files but only allowed me to open one and then recent files list seems to be completely hidden.

Is there some way of accessing this GLOBAL recent list from evince? Also is there any way to get tabbed views working in evince to have all documents in one window?

Comment: "Tabbed view" is a different question and actually would be a feature request.

Comment: I found qpdfview and am trying that out for tabbed viewing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see your recent files again after you have opened a file, click the hamburger menu and click "new window". Unfortunatelly, no hotkey is defined, nor can you define one yourself, to open that window. You still have relatively quick keyboard access with <kbd>F10</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>. Unfortunatelly (again), it is not possible to open several files at once from that overview of recently opened files, so you will need to reopen that "new window" for each other file you want to open.